# Curved DIV Edges in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make these image corners / edges in css but with no result:

[image]

How can I achieve this in CSS?
Here's my attempt, but I can't achieve the exact shape that's in the image.

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hi @andrew-l i'm currently tried this -> http://jsfiddle.net/ECHWb/ but i can't achieve the exact image curves and slices

Comment: Make the div taller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a container div

   - css: `overflow: hidden;`
2. create 3 divs inside the container div

   - one green rectangle (lid) with 
     `border-radius: 50%; z-index: 2; box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;`
   - one left rectangle
   - one right rectangle
   - for all rectangles use: `position: relative;` and reposition them. 
      with `left: [X]px, top: -[Y]px, float: left and float: right`.
3. Use **dynamic measurements** for sizing and positioning,
    so you're layout works responsively : *ex: all based on **vw***.

here's an example fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/mx11fh6b/2/
It's simpler if you just follow the steps.

Comment: I would try this right now and then let you know! Thanks @warkentien2

Comment: Well i tried without success -> https://jsfiddle.net/npqgjfbL/6/ maybe i doing something wrong!

Comment: sorry for the wait. They need dimension (width/height).

Comment: Well i thin i almost closer but white spaces are on the edges -> https://jsfiddle.net/npqgjfbL/10/

Comment: add `height: 200px; top: -100px;` to .rectangle

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version.

```
div{
    background-color:black;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 50%/0 0 50px 50px;
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/ECHWb/787/](http://jsfiddle.net/ECHWb/786/)

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this? what is going on with that border radius?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @warkentien2 the solution in this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/npqgjfbL/10/

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%/0% 0 100px 100px;
  z-index: 2; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

.rectangle {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: -99999;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="rectangle black left">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="rectangle grey right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Thanks all for the help!