# Div with contoured edge based on image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div with an edge that contours to the outline of an image on one side.  Like this:
[image]

With the outlined are being the div.
The closest solution I could find is here: [Curved DIV Edges in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444165/curved-div-edges-in-css)
But that's not quite it.  I'm really just trying to determine if it's even possible or if I should pursue other avenues.

Comment: Can you specify what you're trying to achieve by creating a doodle of it for example?

Comment: Personally, I think it's hard to achieve what you're trying, because the div can't know the content of that image. My best idea would be to create an svg that contains the path of the image line you outlined in your picture and working with clip-path or mask. More on those options here: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: How do you define the 'one side' so that the system can know when to stop? And have you investigated HTML canvas?

Comment: @tstrmn I think that's gonna get it.  Do you want to submit it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @AHaworth That's kinda the problem I'm trying to solve.  HTML canvas only allows for drawing inside a predefined rectangular canvas.

Comment: The idea with canvas would be to remove the black on the left hand side, then using it to create a mask image. But for that you need to know what is left hand side, because in your image there is black, just a tiny bit, at bottom and top. Without that it would be OK. An alternative might be to say left hand side never extends beyond 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best idea would be to create an svg that contains the path of the image line you outlined in your picture and working with clip-path or mask. More on those options here: [css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by @tstrmn got me most of the way there but I wanted to post the rest of what I did in the interest of completion.
After applying an SVG clip-path to the image, I set the image to position:absolute, set the parent div overflow to visible and translated the image over the left edge of the div.  With the clip-path in place on the image this produced the desired result.